# Effects of Retrograde Saturn posited in the 7th house

Tags: astrology, shani, horoscopes, brihat-parashara-hora-shastra

How does one get affected if Saturn is in the 7th House of Relationships, Marriage?. Also what happens if Saturn is Retrograde?.

Comment: This is incomplete information to judge about relationship without knowing sign and other planets, and is like asking if India is in east, how vast is Indian ocean? as planets are mapped on nakshatras(where naksha means map and tra means control).On general basis, Saturn in 7th can lead to delay in marriage but long lasting partner and without divorce, as Saturn represents slowness but stability.7th house is also of career as its 10th from 10th house of occupation(bhavat bhavam concept) & give same effect for occupation, but aspect or conjunction of other planets on Saturn can alter everything

Comment: Retrograde Saturn is like Saturn on steroids and will also effect 6th house(one house behind its placement) which is actually better than natural malefic Saturn alone in 7th kendra house, as natural malefics are preferred in dusthana houses and 6th house is of enemies(poison cuts poison) and with retrograde Saturn can suppress rivalry in work places and diseases with 3rd aspect on 8th house giving long life, especially during sade sati or Saturn mahadasha.

Comment: I have three planets retrograde and apart from that 2 debilitated planets. Since there is no proper study on retrograde planets yet, its very hard to find the proper prediction. My D.O.B is 30-10-1994, 2:30 AM, Erode, Tamilnadu, India. If any of you can find proper prediction, it would be really helpful. I always face failure in relationships be it friends, colleagues or anyone. Will this continue in my marriage life?. If so what precautions I should take?